# How to embed a List in a ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui

**My first attempt**

I'm trying to embedding a List in a ScrollView. Like the code right below.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            myGrid
            
            myList // List is not showing up on the screen
        }
    }

    var myGrid: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
                    .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                    }))
            }
        }
    }
    
    var myList: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
                    .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                    }))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result of my code**

[image]

**My second attempt**

I want to place a List within a ScrollView to enable scrolling for the entire screen, as I am using a LazyVGrid. However, my attempt to embed the LazyVGrid in a List did not produce the desired result. When I interact with buttons or items in the LazyVGrid, the entire row in the List is affected unexpectedly.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            /* this not a good solution all LazyVGrid should be outside of the List
             at the same time I can't select item seperately, all section is affected by context menu
             */
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
                Section {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in
                        Text("Row \(index)")
                            .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                                Text("Menu Item 1")
                                Text("Menu Item 2")
                                Text("Menu Item 3")
                            }))
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
                    .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                    }))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result of the second code**

[image]

**My third attempt**

I'm facing an issue when applying a fixed frame to a List. It doesn't adjust dynamically based on its content. As I add more items, I find myself needing to manually increase the frame size of the list.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 50, maximum: 100), spacing: 16),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            myGrid
            
            /* when I set the frame, it is showing up on the screen
             but now frame is not dynamic. When I try to add more items it should be
             increased automatically. I don't know how to handle it.
             */
            myList
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        }
    }

    var myGrid: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
                    .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                    }))
            }
        }
    }
    
    var myList: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
                    .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                    }))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result of the third code**

[image]

**Note:**
I removed all styling code to simplify the amount of code.

Comment: TBH It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve!

Comment: @SPatel I have edited my post to provide clearer information on what I aim to accomplish. For explain what I want to achieve in a sentence, I have a LazyVGrid and a List, and I want all of them to be scrollable simultaneously.

Comment: You can use ForEach in your third attempt without the List.

Comment: However, I want to use List because it has features like swipe actions and pre-defined styles. For now, I created my own view that looks exactly like List, but I want to use List instead of recreating it to keep the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to display a grid at the beginning of a list. This is working without problems, but the contextmenu which I needed was also behaving the same way as in your attempt #2.

I resolved it by using the `Menu` component like proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394730).

This is the (simplified) structure of my solution:

```swift
List {
    Section {
        LazyVGrid {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Menu {
                    Button("Add", systemImage: "xyz") {}
                    Button("Delete", systemImage: "xyz", role: .destructive) {}
                } label: {
                    Text("Grid item \(item.name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // normal list
    Section {
        Text("List Item 1")
        Text("List Item 2")
        Text("List Item 3")
    }
}
```